# React Native Modal Undefined not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-modal

I want to ask a question that has been asked before but does not have a concrete solution
I am using modal to open somewhere on my homepage in react native(
in HomePage in modal homestack)
When I go to CategoriesStack (I get this error here, but it doesn't matter where) when I change a page, I get the error in the image below, I can't understand where is the problem because it gives the error in modal.js how can i fix it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Updating to latest React-native Modal solved this issue

Answer (score 4):

Updating `react-native-modal` to `13.0.1` or newer solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Those methods were deprecated in 0.70

They can be replaced with the function `.remove()`

[Here's some more info and a discussion](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34644#issuecomment-1245026317)

Answer (score 0):

**removeListener()** method is deprecated in react-native +0.70

in new version we use **subscription?.remove()**

**Solution**

change in your library inside your node_modules

example in my case i have a problem in react-native-modal-datetime-picker
i open file *Project_Name*/node_modules/react-native-modal-datetime-picker/src/Modal.js
and i change code
From this:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    if (this.state.isVisible) {
      this.show();
    }
    DeviceEventEmitter.addListener(
      "didUpdateDimensions",
      this.handleDimensionsUpdate
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    DeviceEventEmitter.removeListener(
      "didUpdateDimensions",
      this.handleDimensionsUpdate
    );
    this._isMounted = false;
  }
```

To this :

```
subscription = null;

  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    if (this.state.isVisible) {
      this.show();
    }
    this.subscription = DeviceEventEmitter.addListener(
      "didUpdateDimensions",
      this.handleDimensionsUpdate
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.subscription?.remove()
    this._isMounted = false;
  }
```

after that you should test if these change work you must use [patch-package](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package) to keep your fixes to npm dependencies

Set-up
In `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
+  "postinstall": "patch-package"
 }
```

Then

```
npm i -D patch-package postinstall-postinstall
```

finally

```
npx patch-package package-name
```

in my case `npx patch-package react-native-modal-datetime-picker`